# Agent's expected utility depends only on mean and variance

Tags: economics, decision-theory

> Consider an agent with the expected utility function $U(L) = \sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_s U(Y_s)$ over the lottery $L = (Y_s, \pi_s)$ where $\pi_s$ is the probability of state $s$, $Y_s$ are state $s$ payoffs, and $U(y_s) = -\frac{1}{2}(\alpha - Y_s)^2$ for $Y_s < \alpha$ is the utility index
>   over payoffs. Show that this agent's expected utility depends upon only
>   the mean and variance of the state-contingent payoffs.

I do not really understand what the question is asking of me to show. Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated. Specifically, is the question asking me to find $$E[U(s_s)]$$ and $$Var[U(Y_s)]$$ if so how do we do that when we don't really have any defined distribution for $Y_s$? Also what does even mean that the mean the agent's expected utility depends upon only the mean and variance of the state-contingent payoffs. Does not make sense to me, I do not have much of an economics background as a graduate student in Applied Mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify the question.

First, writing $U(L)=\sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_{s}U(Y_{s})$ does not make sense. The two $U$ functions are different objects. Correct way is $U(L)=\sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_{s}u(Y_{s})$, were $U$ is expected utility (of lottery $L$) and $u$ is Bernoulli utility (of payoff $Y_{s}$). $U$ is a function that lives on space of lotteries. $u$ is a function that lives on space of real numbers. It is the Bernoulli utility that is quadratic, that is, $u(x)=-\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-x)^{2}$.

Second, a lottery is $L=(Y_{s},\pi_{s})_{s=1}^{S}$. That is, for each state $s\in\{1,\ldots,S\}$, it gives probability of $s$ occurring, $\pi_{s}$, and (state-contingent) payoff/return from the lottery, $Y_{s}$, in $s$. Namely, $Y_{s}$ is a number (e.g. amount of money you win in state $s$), not a random variable. Lottery $L$ is a random variable. One that gives realization $Y_{s}$ with probability $\pi_{s}$ and has discrete support. (In view of the convention to denote r.v.s by capital letters, this notation is unfortunate. Let me switch to $y_{s}$ then.)

Since $L$ is r.v., $\sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_{s}=1$. Let me denote by $\mu_{L}=\sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_{s}y_{s}$ mean (return) of the lottery $L$. Let me denote by $\sigma^{2}_{L}=\sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_{s}(y_{s}-\mu_{L})^{2}=\left(\sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_{s}y_{s}^{2}\right)-\mu_{L}^{2}$ variance (of returns) of the lottery (the last equality is standard algebra, in fact the equation is discrete version of $\mathbb{E}[x^{2}]-\mathbb{E}[x]^{2}$).

So now we have $U(L)=\sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_{s}u(y_{s})$, $u(y_{s})=-\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-y_{s})^{2}$, $L=(y_{s},\pi_{s})_{s=1}^{S}$. We want to show $U(L)$ depends only on mean and variance of the lottery. We have 
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
U(L)&=-\tfrac{1}{2}\sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_{s}(\alpha^{2}-2\alpha y_{s}+y_{s}^{2})\\
&=-\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\alpha^{2}-2\alpha\sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_{s}y_{s}+\sum_{s=1}^{S}\pi_{s}y_{s}^{2}\right)\\
&=-\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\alpha^{2}-2\alpha\mu_{L}+\sigma^{2}_{L}+\mu_{L}^{2}\right)\\
&=-\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\sigma_{L}^{2}+(\alpha-\mu_{L})^{2}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
which is what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

First obtain the mean and variance of the state-contingent payoffs, which are random variables that with probability $\pi_s$ take value $Y_s$ (you win the lottery!) and with probability $1-\pi_s$ take value $0$. Call these means and variances $\mu_s$ and var$_s$.

Now try to rewrite $E[U(\cdot)]$ using only the quantities $\mu_s$ and var$_s$ in the formula, and in particular avoiding any reference $U(\cdot)$ or $\pi_s$. That's what the question is about.

Note: if the problem is from a textbook, add a reference so other people can find it!

Comment: I see, so am I computing $E[U(Y_s)]$ and $Var[U(Y_s)]$?

Comment: Ok, then I am completely lost, how can one compute $E[Y_s]$ when $Y_s$ is not explicitly defined?

Comment: I probably did not make myself very clear, sorry.
You don't "compute it". Just see if you can write $E[U(y_s)]$ (who cares about the variance of the utility function? the question only mentions the expectation) as a function of the sole unknowns $E[y_s]$, $Var[y_s]$, by plugging those values "appropriately" into the expression of $E[U(\cdot)]$. 
Note that $y_s$ is the random variable, $Y_s$ is the positive value it takes with probability $\pi_s$. Better now?

Comment: Seems to me that we have $$E[U(y_s)] = -\frac{1}{2}\left(E[Y_s^2] - 2aE[Y_s] + a^2\right)$$ dont really know where to go from there, perhaps at this point you could expand on your answer.

Comment: First of all, do not confuse $Y_s$, the constant, with $y_s$, the variable. $Y_s$ should not appear in your formula! Then, if you can write (you are almost there!) the expression using only $E[y_s]$ and $Var[y_s]$, and sum up for all the $s$ (the agent has many tickets; what happens to $E[y_i y_j]$) for $i\neq j$?), you have answered the question: you have a formula for $E[U(\cdot)]$ that depends solely on $E[y_s]$ and $Var[y_s]$. Almost there!

Comment: I am sort of confused, $U(y_s) = -\frac{1}{2}(\alpha - Y_s)^2$ for $Y_s < \alpha$ so how did I apply $E[U(y_s)]$ incorrectly?