# Show the expected value of a function is greater than the expected value of another

Tags: expectation, economics

> Consider two distributions
>
> $$F(x) =\begin{cases}
>  0 &\text{if} \ \ x < 0\\
> \frac{1}{4} &\text{if} \ \ 0\leq x < 2\\
> 1 &\text{if} \ \  2\leq x
> \end{cases}$$
>   and 
>   $$G(x) =\begin{cases}
>  0 &\text{if} \ \ x < 1\\
> 1 &\text{if} \ \ 1\leq x \\
> \end{cases}$$
>   Show that the expected value of $x$ under $F$ is greater than the expected value of $x$ under $G$ but that $F$ does not first-order stochastically dominate $G$.

Attemped solution - It seems the expected value of both distributions will be infinity, so I do not know how to show the latter. For first-order stochastic dominance we have $$U(F) = \int_{-\infty}^{0}dx + \int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{4}dx + \int_{2}^{\infty}dx$$
again it does not seem that we will get any meaningful evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you the details that you need for this and have you fill in any details (or ask me, and I can put them in). Let $\mathbb{E}_{F}[X]$ be the expected value of $X$ under $F$, and similarly for $\mathbb{E}_{G}[X]$.

Notice that $F$ is a distribution function and not a probability mass/density function - so you would not be integrating or summing $F$, but integrating or summing the probability density or probability mass function, respectively. This applies similarly to $G$.

$F$ is constant throughout, so that means there are point masses. The probability mass function corresponding to $F$ consists of a probability mass of $\dfrac{1}{4}$ at $x = 0$ and a probability mass of $\dfrac{3}{4}$ at $x = 2$. Hence,
$$\mathbb{E}_{F}[X] = \dfrac{1}{4}(0)+\dfrac{3}{4}(2)=\dfrac{6}{4}=1.5\text{.}$$

Similarly for $G$, there is a probability mass of $1$ at $x = 1$, hence
$$\mathbb{E}_{G}[X] = 1(1) = 1\text{.}$$
Hence, $\mathbb{E}_{F}[X] > \mathbb{E}_{G}[X]$.

[$F$ does not first-order stochastically dominate $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#First-order_stochastic_dominance). If this were the case, then $F(x) \leq G(x)$ for all $x$ with strict inequality at some $x$. However, for $x \in [0, 1)$, $F(x) = \dfrac{1}{4}$ and $G(x) = 0$ so $F(x) > G(x)$.

Comment: I do not see how we have a point mass of $\frac{3}{4}$ at $x=2$?

Comment: @ILoveMath Notice how $F$, the *cumulative* distribution function, "jumps" from $\dfrac{1}{4}$ to $1$ at $x = 2$. For this to have happened, a point mass of $\dfrac{3}{4}$ at $x = 2$ must have been added.

Comment: Ok, I see thank you. For the rest I understand, although, I do not see what other details that would need to be added for this to be a complete solution, it seems complete to me

Comment: @ILoveMath Good to hear. Don't forget to mark this as a best answer if you liked it. :)

Comment: You seem good at this. Here is another question if you know it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096974/agents-expected-utility-depends-only-on-mean-and-variance